# Cohomological dimension for stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, etale-cohomology, d-modules

If $X$ is a scheme (maybe with conditions), I'm pretty sure that the ($\ell$-adic/de Rham) rational cohomology $H^*(X,\mathcal{F}$) of an $\ell$-adic sheaf/holonomic $D$-module $\mathcal{F}$ vanishes above some degree $d(X)<\infty$. Say that $X$ has *finite cohomological dimension*. This does not hold for Artin stacks, e.g. $H^*(BG,k)$ lives in arbitrarily high degrees for most positive-dimensional $G$. Thus I imagine there is a theorem of the  form

*Theorem(?):* For all Deligne-Mumford stacks (or maybe only algebraic space?) $X$ (with conditions?), $X$ has finite cohomological dimension.

**Question:** Does such a theorem exist, either in the $\ell$-adic or the $D$-module form? If so, what is a good reference?

Comment: What if $X$ is the disjoint union of complex projective spaces of each dimension?

Comment: @Faris Yeah, I guess $X$ should should be of finite type

Comment: And it is also necessary to make assumptions on the cohomological dimension of the base field! Let's maybe assume the base field is algebraically closed. Then I think the statement is true for all DM-stacks $X$ of finite type. This is definitely true for quotient stacks by etale group schemes: you get a spectral sequence converging from the cohomology of a (finite) group with coefficients in the cohomology of a finite type scheme.. I guess it should also be true that if $U\rightarrow X$ is an etale cover, then rat. cohomological dimension of $X$ is bounded by the cohomological dimension of $U$

Comment: but I can't recall the argument

Comment: I explained this to a graduate student a couple of weeks ago.  There is a quasi-finite, proper $1$-morphism from the stack to a "coarse moduli space".  Etale locally, this morphism is the coarse moduli space of a finite quotient stack (you can find a proof in Abramovich-Vistoli).  Thus, by the argument in the previous comment, the higher direct images vanish for "rational" $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$-coefficients.  Combined with the Leray spectral sequence, cohomological dimension of the stack equals cohomological dimension of the coarse moduli space.

Comment: @JasonStarr I've just realised I don't actually understand the argument that $R^if_*\mathbf{Q}_\ell=0$ for $i>0$ and $f$ is the coarse moduli space of a DM stack. Is there a proof of this written anywhere?